# How to drop all Tables and UDTs from a Cassandra Keyspace?

Tags: cassandra

Is there any way to clear a keyspace in Cassandra? We cannot drop the keyspace directly, as we don't have rights to create or drop keyspaces.
Thank you in advance!

P.S. we are using Cassandra 3.7.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing it via `cqlsh` is quite straightforward, and it's better than try to implement something using the custom code - there are nuances of the programmatic schema changes, that it's better to avoid:

Full script to drop everything is here:

```sh
cqlsh -e 'describe keyspace test;' > ks.cql
rm -f drop-all.cql
grep -e '^CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW' ks.cql|sed -e 's|^CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW \(.*\) ($|DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW \1;|' >> drop-all.cql
grep -e '^CREATE INDEX' ks.cql|sed -e 's|^CREATE INDEX \(.*\) ($|DROP INDEX \1;|' >> drop-all.cql
grep -e '^CREATE TABLE' ks.cql|sed -e 's|^CREATE TABLE \(.*\) ($|DROP TABLE \1;|' >> drop-all.cql
grep -e '^CREATE TYPE' ks.cql|sed -e 's|^CREATE TYPE \(.*\) ($|DROP TYPE \1;|' >> drop-all.cql
cqlsh -f drop-all.cql
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like cqlsh -e 'use ;describe tables'. This will return a list of tables that you can use to create queries to delete those tables. Similar with udt's.

Comment: Thanks!
Right now, we are doing the same. But our schema is too big and it changes frequently. We are looking for any kind of command or client (like achilles schema creator).